# What specs are required, and what software do I need to make a Render Farm?

Tags: rendering

I'm sending .blend files to a new render farm that has dedicated machines that have never run blender before.  What machine specs are required, and what software do I need to make sure is present?

Comment: Are you asking for minimal system specs? It's not that hard to find: https://lmgtfy.com/?q=blender+minimum+system+specs

Answer (score 1):

#### Hardware:

(pictures from the blender website) https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/
[image: MaxHardware]
[image: minHardware]

Since you are running a "Render Farm," you do not need the monitors, mice, or graphics tablets.

I would recommend buying good graphics cards for your nodes, as GPUs seem to increase render speed by quite a lot.

---

#### Software:

---

All you need is linux, windows, or MacOS and blender (https://www.blender.org/)